# Is it possible to define a logical system as a set or system of functions?

Tags: functions, logic

Is it possible to define a logical system as a set or system of functions? If so, which fields should one learn to do this?

Comment: You might be interested in the notion of the "category of proofs", see for example: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/proof, or https://youtu.be/ZKmodCApZwk?t=31m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly, but possibly this is precisely what the field of *abstract algebraic logic* is all about. In this theory you befenit from the simple fact that logical connectives are basicaly nothing else than operations on algebras, i.e. functions.

In more details let  $\mathcal{L}$ be a set of function symbols, called *language* and $\mathbf{A}$ an algebra in this language. Moreover let $F$ be a subset of its universe, called *filter* (or *truth set*), which serves to inverpret truth values. Together $\langle\mathbf{A},F\rangle$ is called a *logical matrix*. Then you can define logic, denote its consequence relation by turnstile $\vdash$, in a following way: for every formulas (terms) $\Gamma\cup\{A\} $

$$\Gamma\vdash_{\langle\mathbf{A},F\rangle} A \text{ if and only if for every evaluation } v: Term \to A:\, v[\Gamma]\subseteq F\text{ implies } v(A)\in F, $$

where an evaluation $v$ is a homomorphism from free term (free formula) algera $Term$  to $\mathbf{A}$. In other words from set of formulas $\Gamma$ you can infer a formula $A$ whenever every evaluation satisfying $\Gamma$ also satisfyies $A$ (truth means being member of $F$).

For a class of such a matrices $\mathbb{K}$ define:

$$\Gamma\vdash_\mathbb{K}A \text{ if and only if for every } \langle\mathbf{A},F\rangle\in\mathbb{K} \text{ it holds }\Gamma\vdash_{\langle\mathbf{A},F\rangle} A$$

This way for example classical logic can be obtained as $\vdash_{\langle\mathbf{2},\{1\}\rangle}$, where $\mathbf{2}$ is the Boolean algebra of two elements. Or you can get intuitionistic logic as $\vdash_\mathbb{K}$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is the class of all matrices based on Heyting algeras with truth sets $\{1\}$. Another famous examples are logics based on algbras over the real unit interval $[0,1]$ (e.g. fuzzy logics).

Every logic defined this way has the following noteworthy features (which in the context of abstract algebraic logic actually serves as a definition of what a (propositional) logic should be).

- if $A\in \Gamma$ then $\Gamma\vdash A$,
- if $\Gamma\vdash A$ and $\Gamma\subseteq\Delta$ then $\Delta\vdash A$,
- if $\Gamma\vdash A$ for every $A\in \Delta$ and $\Delta\vdash B$ then $\Gamma\vdash B$,
- if $\Gamma\vdash\ A$ and $\sigma$ is a substitution then $\sigma[\Gamma]\vdash \sigma(A)$.

All of these conditions are rather obvious, maybe except for the last one which  basically asserts that consequence in propositional logic is about form and not about context. So a consequence of a form $\Gamma\vdash A$ will be true under any 'circumstance' provided by the substitution $\sigma$,. This property is usually called *structurality*.